# How to use " instead of ' to generate Json strings

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to use `"` instead of `'`.

```
countryid="be"
msg = "{'field1': 'abc','field2': '"+countryid+"', 'field3': '1'}"
```

I tried to use `"""` as follows:

```
msg = """{"field1": "abc","field2": """"+countryid+"""", "field3": "1"}"""
```

But then I get:

```
{"field1": "abc","field2": +countryid+, "field3": "1"}
```

instead of:

```
{"field1": "abc","field2": "be", "field3": "1"}
```

Comment: Don't create JSON as string! Create a normal Python dictionary and use `json.dumps(your_dict)`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give an answer to your questions, however I think the question you are asking may be slightly wrong.

The issue you are facing is due to the unfortunate placement of the start quote for the *countryid*

```
msg = """{"field1": "abc","field2": """"+countryid+"""", "field3": "1"}"""
                                    ^^^^
                                    ||||
```

The python documentation for string literals says:

> In triple-quoted strings, unescaped newlines and quotes are allowed
>   (and are retained), except that three unescaped quotes in a row
>   terminate the string. (A ``quote'' is the character used to open the
>   string, i.e. either ' or ".)

So you have many options to fix your issue:

1) Escape the problematic quote:

```
msg = """{"field1": "abc","field2": \""""+countryid+"""", "field3": "1"}"""
                                    ^
                                    |
```

2) Use single quotes:

```
msg = '{"field1": "abc","field2": "'+countryid+'", "field3": "1"}'
```

3) Use string formatting:

```
msg = """{"field1": "abc","field2": "%s", "field3": "1"}""" % countryid
                                      ^                     ^    ^
                                      |                     |    |
```

There are even more options if you're using python 3.6 and later or if you're willing to use a library.

This is one of the areas of the Python language where the "zen of python" principle of "one obvious way to do something" is broken

Note that all of the methods I've explained above are not actually a good way of generating JSON.

Here is how I'd do it if I were you:

```
import json
countryid= "someone's ID"
message = {'field1': 'abc','field2': countryid,'field3': '1'}
msg = json.dumps(messsage)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use json module

```
import json
countryid="be"
msg = {
    'field1': 'abc',
    'field2': countryid,
    'field3': '1'
}
print(json.dumps(msg))
```